# WebMethod not being called although Success returned

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webmethod

I have an ASP.NET Web forms site with C# code behind called from VS2013 running under Win 10 and viewed in Google Chrome. I am trying to call a C# function from Javascript in the Default.aspx markup as shown below

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
     <textarea id="txtPaste" placeholder="Paste Image Here" style="height: 100px;"></textarea>
    <img id="imgPaste"  src="C:\Users\Simon\Pictures\Download via Dropbox a.jpg"/>
    <asp:Button Text="Save" runat="server" OnClick="Save" />
     <input id="Text1" type="text" name ="ImageData"  hidden="hidden" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById('txtPaste').focus();
        document.getElementById('txtPaste').onpaste = function (event) {
            var items = (event.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(items));
            var blob = null;
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                if (items[i].type.indexOf("image") === 0) {
                    blob = items[i].getAsFile();
                }
            }
            if (blob !== null) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (event) {                  
                document.getElementById("imgPaste").src = event.target.result;
                document.getElementById("Text1").value = event.target.result;
                PageMethods.SaveImg(event.target.result.toString(), onSuccess, onFailure); 
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
            }
        }
    };
    function onSuccess(result) {
        alert("Success! " + result);
    }
    function onFailure(result) {
        alert("Failed! " + result);
    } 
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

The PageMethod is defined in Default.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Services;

public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Save(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = Request.Form["ImageData"];
        SaveImg(str);
    }
    [WebMethod]
    public static bool SaveImg(string str)
    {
        try
        {
            string imageData = str.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
            var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);
            string filePath = @"C:\Windows\Temp\File.jpg";
            if (File.Exists(filePath)) File.Delete(filePath);
            using (var imageFile = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                imageFile.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                imageFile.Flush();
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {           
                return true;
        }
    }
}
```

When I click in txtPaste and paste an image, the image appears in imgPaste OK and can be downloaded as a file by clicking by the Save button to execute the SaveImg function.

I am trying to create the file only by pasting an image, without clicking the Save button by defining SaveImg as Web Method and calling PageMethods.SaveImg after filling the Image control. The call to SaveImg shows and alert as specified in the OnSuccess function, but SaveImg is not executed - breakpoints set in the function are not hit on the Paste event, although they are if the Save button is clicked. The same behaviour is shown if the web site is viewed in Firefox.

ScriptManager in the Master.aspx file has EnablePageMethods set to True.

I have tried the following to make SaveImg execute on the paste event without success:

1) Commenting out settings.AutoredirectMode in Route.Config made PageMethods.SaveImg return a Fail status.

2) Commenting one or both lines in global.asax:

```
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

3) Using an AJAX function as shown below. sParam was defined as event.target.result.toString() and the call replaced the PageMethods.SaveImg call

```
function showDetail(sParam) {       
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST", 
            url: "Default.aspx/SaveImg", 
            data: "{'str': '" +sParam +"'}", // passing the parameter 
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
            dataType: "json", 
            success: function(retValue) {
                // Do something with the return value from.Net method
            } 
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling a C# function from Javascript in ASP.Net can be done by placing the C# function in the click event of a control and then calling the control's click event from Javascript as shown below for the above scenario:

JavaScript in page markup:

```
%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
     <textarea id="txtPaste" name="txtPaste" placeholder="Paste Image Here" style="height: 100px;"></textarea>
    <img id="imgPaste"  src="C:\Users\Simon\Pictures\Download via Dropbox a.jpg"/>
    <asp:Button Text="Save" runat="server" OnClick="cmdSave_Click" ID="cmdSave" />
     <input id="Text1" type="hidden" name ="ImageData"  hidden="hidden" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById('txtPaste').focus();
        document.getElementById('txtPaste').onpaste = function (event) {
            var items = (event.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(items));
            var blob = null;
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                if (items[i].type.indexOf("image") === 0) {
                    blob = items[i].getAsFile();
                }
            }
            if (blob !== null) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (event) {                  
                document.getElementById("imgPaste").src = event.target.result;
                document.getElementById("Text1").value = event.target.result;
                //PageMethods.SaveImg(event.target.result.toString(), onSuccess, onFailure);
                document.getElementById("txtPaste").value = "Image Pasted"
                document.getElementById("cmdSave").click();
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
            }
        }
    };

</script>
```

C# code:

```
protected void cmdSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = Request.Form["ImageData"];
        SaveImg(str);
    }
    public  bool SaveImg(string str)
    {
        try
        {
            string imageData = str.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
            var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);
            string filePath = @"C:\Windows\Temp\File.jpg";
            if (File.Exists(filePath)) File.Delete(filePath);
            using (var imageFile = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                imageFile.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                imageFile.Flush();
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {           
                return true;
        }
    }
```